# Calling functions on intercepted method invocations in Simple Injector

Tags: c#, simple-injector, interception

What I am trying to achieve is to intercept the injection of a class, and call a specific method on the class to alter it's behaviour.

I have implemented the [interceptor class](https://simpleinjector.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=InterceptionExtensions&referringTitle=Advanced-scenarios") that is given on the SimpleInjector website, and this is working, so I am able to get some functionality running when the class is intercepted.

My container is registering it as such:

```
container.InterceptWith<MyInterceptor>(type => type == typeof(IMyClass));
```

The class I am intercepting on looks as such:

```
public class MyClass : IMyClass
{
    private IAnotherClass m_class;
    public MyClass(IAnotherClass _class)
    {
         m_class = _class;
    }

    public void MethodToCall()
    {
         //changes properties on class
    }
}
```

My interceptor class looks as such:

```
public class MyInterceptor : IInterceptor
{
    private readonly ILogger logger;

    public MyInterceptor(ILogger logger)
    {
        this.logger = logger;
    }

    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        var watch = Stopwatch.StartNew();

        // Calls the decorated instance.
        invocation.Proceed();

        var decoratedType = invocation.InvocationTarget.GetType();

        logger.Trace(string.Format("{0} executed in {1} ms.",
            decoratedType.Name, watch.ElapsedTicks));
    }
}
```

What I am trying to achieve is to call a method on the intercepted IMyClass.  So in the interceptor, call `MyClass.MethodToCall()`

I have tried to do something like this in the `Intercept()` method:

```
var classIntercepted = invocation.ReturnValue;
MethodInfo method = invocation.InvocationTarget.GetType().GetMethod("MethodToCall");
object magicValue = method.Invoke(classIntercepted, null);
```

But, the `invocation.ReturnValue` is not returning the `MyClass` instance, but rather the `IAnotherClass` instance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use a decorator instead of using interception? This is often much easier, more maintainable and faster.

Here's an example:

```
public class PropSetMyClassDecorator : IMyClass
{
    private MyClass decoratee;
    public PropSetMyClassDecorator(MyClass decoratee) {
        this.decoratee = decoratee;
    }

    public void MethodToCall() {
        this.decoratee.SetConnectionString();
        this.decoratee.MethodToCall();
    }
}
```

You can register this decorator as follows:

```
container.Register<IMyClass, PropSetMyClassDecorator>();
```

Do note that instead of registering `MyClass`, we only register the decorator. Since the decorator directly depends on `MyClas`s (not on the interface) `MyClass` will be automatically resolved by Simple Injector.

Yet another option is to register an initializer as follows:

```
container.RegisterInitializer<MyClass>(instance => {
    instance.SetConnectionString();
});
```

The initializer delegate will be called every time after a `MyClass` instance is constructed. The behavior is a bit different in this case, since the method isn't called every time, but only during construction. Usually however, this should be sufficient,  since you should normally not change a service during runtime, since you are complicating things.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, found a solution fairly shortly after posting the question.

I changed my `Intercept` function to be the following:

```
    public void Intercept(IInvocation invocation)
    {
        // Calls the decorated instance.
        invocation.Proceed();

        var classIntercepted = invocation.InvocationTarget;
        MethodInfo method = invocation.InvocationTarget.GetType().GetMethod("SetConnectionString");
        method.Invoke(classIntercepted, null);
    }
```